# Document look-up of PDFs

Tags: document-library, lookup-column

I have a look-up to the Documents list on the Title column, containing a mixture of DOCX and PDF files.

The DOCX files appear in the drop-down, but the PDFs seem to be ignored. I can open the PDF fine when browsing to it directly, just that in the lookup, the PDF documents don't appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately by default only the Name field is filled when you upload a non-Office document.

And to make it even worse you can't use the Name field for a lookup. So to make it work you have to enter information into the Title field for each document.

The easist (if you don't have access to code) is to create a view with Name and Title next the each other and then open that view in Datasheet mode.

If you can add code then an event receiver filling out title when empty is a very good investment

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint: Displaying PDFs from a Dropdown Menu](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/12/sharepoint-displaying-pdfs-from.html)